# Unable to write files in python

Tags: python, file

Today, I was testing my old python script, it was about fetching some details from an API and write then in a file. Until my last test it was working perfectly fine but today when I executed the script it worked, I mean no error at all but it neither write nor created any file. The API is returning complete data - I tested on it terminal, then I created another test.py file to check if file write statements are working, so the result was - they were not working.
I don't know what is causing the issue, it also ain't giving any error.

This is my sample TEST.PY file

```
filename = "domain.log"

with open(filename, 'a') as domain_file:
    domain_file.write("HELLO\n")
    domain_file.write("ANOTHER HELLO\n")
```

Thank you

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Maybe you are not checking the right place? It created the file and wrote in it. Then running it again, it simply appends.

Comment: I don't know what was causing the issue, it is now working for me too. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Using `'a'` on the `open` call to open the file in append mode (as shown in your code) should work just fine.

I don't think your issue is on the Python side.  The next thing to check are your directory permissions:

```
$ ls -al domain.log
-rw-r--r--  1 taylor  staff  60 Apr 16 07:57 domain.log
```

Here's my output after running your code a few times:

```
$ cat domain.log
HELLO
ANOTHER HELLO
HELLO
ANOTHER HELLO
HELLO
ANOTHER HELLO
```

Comment: "a" works - if a file does not exist, it gets created.whats being written to it, is appended.

Comment: Then I think your code is fine.  Check that you have permission to write to disk with `ls -al domain.log`.

Comment: Thank you - updated my answer with sample output for verification.

Comment: thank you so much, I tested the script again, it is now working, I don't know what was causing the issue but it is now working

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to file permission or its directory. Use `ls -la` to see file and folder permissions.